Firebase query for a collection with array of maps returns not working
I am trying to query my Firebase database.

I wrote the following code to pull the list of groups where a specific user is a member. The code is appended below. When I run the code, it returns nothing. I tried to query directly using query builder in the console, however, it does not work there either.
I have been at this for sometime but cannot seem to find the issue. Can someone help me out?
Widget _buildGroupsList() {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .where(
          'members',
          arrayContainsAny: [
            {'id': user.uid}
          ],
        )
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
      }


      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      final List<Widget> groupCards = [];

      for (var doc in snapshot.data!.docs) {
        Map<String, dynamic> groupData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        groupCards.add(_buildGroupCard(groupData));
      }

      return ListView(
        children: groupCards,
      );
    },
  );
}


I built the query in the console and it did not return the data either. It did not throw and error. It just did not return anything.

It's not possible with Firestore to filter documents using just a single property of an object in an array.  You must know the entire contents of an object in order to filter it from an array.  If you want to do this query, you will need a different document structure, perhaps one that has a dedicated array with only user IDs that you can filter with an array-contains query.

Thank you. I ended up adding an array field to the groups collection to store the list of ids for all members in the group. This allows me to use the arrayContains.
